# How do I code border for only part of the <div>?

Tags: html, border

I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

1-pixer border around the div and a 2-pixel border for part of the side that creates the shadow effect. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: There is none, at least not using `border` or `outline`. This should be doable with a real CSS shadow, though? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a `box-shadow`:

```
.content {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 2px #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9YfTf/).

Answer (score 1):

best way to achieve this is with two div's. one with the border set to black all around
and the second div partially bordered

like so
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RPDEv/)

inner div: `border:solid 1px #000;`

outer div: `border:solid 5px #BBB; border-top:none; border-left:none;`

for compatibility sake **box-shadow** will not work in older browsers

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
}
```

That allows you to have a border you're looking for and the box shadow going down and right.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MykeArgyle/pb7yb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood correctly, try:

```
.content {
     border: 1px solid black; /* The border around the div. */
     border-right: 2px solid black; /* The borders where the shadow comes from. */
     border-bottom: 2px solid-black;

     /* and now the shadow */

     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #000;
}
```